# In ASP.NET Core is there a better way to validate required fields?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core Web API project. When adding required fields I do something like this for fields in the body.

```
public record PostModel
{
    [Required]
    public Guid? IdOfSomething { get; init; }
}
```

or if it's a query param I often write them directly into the controller method param list like this

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetSomething([Required] Guid? IdOfSomething) 
{
}
```

The point of interest being that I make required params nullable for types like guid or datetime, because I've found if I don't they get set to a default value and don't automatically producing a model validation error response. However since everything is nullable, when I get into the endpoint implementation I end up having to check for nulls anyway. At which point I'm not sure what the value of having the attribute is.

Basically I'm looking for a solution where

1. Required fields left empty result in model validation error response sent. Preferably before we even hit the body of the controller method.
2. All required params can be accessed without having to check for null values

I could suppress compiler warnings for nullable objects or throw in an '!' every time I access the required params, but I don't like either of these.

I've tried nullable and non nullable types. I've written custom validation attributes. If I use non nullable types I could do a validation failure if the param is set to the default value for that type, but maybe " 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" is a perfectly valid guid that I don't want to fail the validation. If I allow nulls I have the same problem as using the built in required attribute.

Comment: I'm confused. Why don't you just make the parameters non-nullable? That will throw errors if an attempt is made to provide nulls for those values. You'll have to deal with model validation errors, but you appear to know about those. However, you are combining parameter validation and property validation into one question with nary a pause; I'd separate those in your mind and deal with them separately.

Comment: It is too strange to use `[Required]` and `?` together.

Comment: Why not create a custom model binder that checks for null values and returns a 400 Bad Request response if a required field is null. This would allow you to use non-nullable types for your required fields, while still enforcing the requirement.

Comment: @HereticMonkey If you make the property non null, and someone's client sends you JSON without that property the value will be set to the default value for that type instead of triggering a model validation error response message. If someone leaves out a date field in their POST asp.net will attempt to insert 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM

Comment: @Xinran Shen it's not weird, but I'd prefer not to have to check every value for nulls. in the body of my controller method when I've already marked the property as required.

Comment: @Kozydot I'll give this a shot

Answer (score 0):

We added a model state checker that runs at the top of each controller action that checks for any mis-shaped data. If you don't care about logging it only returning 400 then you can simplify. It looks like:

```
if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
{
    this.logger.LogInvalidModelState(this.ModelState);
    return this.BadRequest(this.ModelState);
}
```

and `LogInvalidModelState` looks like

```
public static class LoggerExtensions
{
/// <summary>
/// Logs information about an invalid model state.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="source">The logger.</param>
/// <param name="modelState">The model state.</param>
public static void LogInvalidModelState(this ILogger source, ModelStateDictionary modelState)
{
    var modelStateEntries = new List<ModelStateEntry>();
    var errorMessages = new List<string>();

    Visit(modelState.Root, modelStateEntries);

    foreach (var modelStateEntry in modelStateEntries)
    {
        foreach (var error in modelStateEntry.Errors)
            errorMessages.Add(error.ErrorMessage);
    }

    source.LogError("Invalid Model State: {ErrorMessages}", errorMessages);
}

/// <summary>
/// Adds all non-container nodes of an <see cref="ModelStateEntry"/> to the provided collection.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="modelStateEntry">The current model state entry.</param>
/// <param name="modelStateEntries">A collection of model state entries.</param>
private static void Visit(ModelStateEntry modelStateEntry, ICollection<ModelStateEntry> modelStateEntries)
{
    if (modelStateEntry.Children != null)
    {
        foreach (var child in modelStateEntry.Children)
            Visit(child, modelStateEntries);
    }

    if (!modelStateEntry.IsContainerNode)
        modelStateEntries.Add(modelStateEntry);
}
}
```